# infinite change of constant array as prop in reactjs when parent's state is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component, rerender

so i have this custom component  :

```js
export interface PickerProps extends Omit<SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, 'onChange' | 'name' | 'onInput'> {
    onChange?: OnChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>,
    onChangeValue?: OnChangeValueHandler,
    onInput?: OnInputEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>,
    onInputValueChange?: OnInputChangeHandler,
    name: string,
    label: string,
    emptyOpt?: boolean,
    optGroups: {
        optTitle?: string,
        options: (Omit<OptionHTMLAttributes<HTMLOptionElement>, 'value'> & {
            value: string
        })[]
    }[]
}

export const Picker = ({
    disabled = false,
    autoComplete = "autoComplete",
    onChange = () => { },
    onChangeValue = () => { },
    onInput = () => { },
    onInputValueChange = () => { },
    autoFocus = false,
    size,
    name,
    form = '',
    optGroups = [],
    label,
    emptyOpt = true,
}: PickerProps) => {
    const [pickerValue, setPickerValue] = useState<string>();
    const pickerRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
    const changeHandler = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        const targetValue = e.target.value;
        onChange(e, name);
        onChangeValue(targetValue, name);
        // setPickerValue(targetValue);
    }

    const onInputHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        onInput(e, name);
        //@ts-ignore
        onInputValueChange(e.target.value, name);
        //@ts-ignore
        setPickerValue(e.target.value, name);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const selectedValuesArr = [...optGroups].map(optGroup => optGroup.options
            .filter(opt => opt.selected ?? false)
            .map(sOPT => sOPT.value))
            .reduce((pv, cv) => [...pv, ...cv], []);
        const defValue = selectedValuesArr[0] ?? '';
        setPickerValue(defValue);
        setTimeout(() => pickerRef.current?.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true })), 2);
    }, [optGroups, name]);

    return <>
        <div className="picker-box" tabIndex={0}>
            <span>
                {label}
            </span>
            <select
                ref={pickerRef}
                disabled={disabled}
                autoFocus={autoFocus}
                size={size}
                name={name}
                form={form}
                autoComplete={autoComplete}
                onChange={changeHandler}
                multiple={false}
                value={pickerValue}
                onInput={onInputHandler}
            >
                {emptyOpt && (
                    <option value="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                )}
                {optGroups.map((optGroup, key) => (
                    <optgroup key={key} label={optGroup.optTitle ?? 'انتخاب کنید'}>
                        {optGroup.options.map((opt, index) =>

                            <option
                                className={pickerValue === opt.value ? ' selected' : ''}
                                key={index}
                                disabled={opt.disabled}
                                value={opt.value}
                            >
                                {opt.label ?? ''}
                            </option>
                        )}
                    </optgroup>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    </>;
};
```

and here is an example of how i am using

```js
                <Picker
                    emptyOpt={false}
                    label="تخفیف نقدی"
                    name="cashFlag"
                    optGroups={[
                        {
                            options: [
                                { value: 'true', label: 'دارد', selected: true },
                                { value: 'false', label: 'ندارد' },
                            ]
                        }
                    ]}
                    onInputValueChange={formDataHandler}
                />
```

and this is my form handler :

```js
    const formDataHandler = useCallback((value: string, name: string) => {
            setFormState(fs => {
                const temp = { ...fs };
                temp[name] = value;
                return { ...temp };
            });
    }, []);
```

the array given to the `optGroups` prop is used to render the picker component .
the problem is , whenever the `formDataHandler` function which is the form data change handler , is executed . picker components detect `optGroups` prop changed . while it's not.
arrays given to the Picker components are constant and are not being changed (except two)
and more important and weird thing is that . they all act as expected until the state of parent component is changed ! which is clearly have nothing to do with the Picker components .

i need help to find out why `optGroups` are being detected as new arrays as soon as parent state is changed , while the given arrays are not being changed . (which causes them to call their changeHandler and an infinite loop begins)
first i thought this is my problem :

[ReactJS - When I change a state, props change too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662599/reactjs-when-i-change-a-state-props-change-too)

but , after years of doing this i am sure inside the Picker component , no where the array given as optGroups is being changed .

thanks for any help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is you are creating a new `optGroups` array whenever the parent component renders creating a new reference each time.

```
<Picker
  emptyOpt={false}
  label="تخفیف نقدی"
  name="cashFlag"
  // you are creating a brand new array here each time on re-render. 
  // The reference of the array here changes whenever this component re-renders.
  optGroups={[
    {
      options: [
        { value: "true", label: "دارد", selected: true },
        { value: "false", label: "ندارد" },
      ],
    },
  ]}
  onInputValueChange={formDataHandler}
/>;
```

Declare a constant `optGroupsOptions` outside your Parent component or in a separate file and use it

```
const optGroupsOptions = [
  {
    options: [
      { value: "true", label: "دارد", selected: true },
      { value: "false", label: "ندارد" },
    ],
  },
];

// Use the optGroupsOptions 

<Picker
emptyOpt={false}
label="تخفیف نقدی"
name="cashFlag"
optGroups={optGroupsOptions}
onInputValueChange={formDataHandler}
/>
```

Another approach is to make sure the reference doesn't change between the reference by using the `useMemo` hook .

```
const memoizedOptGroups = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      options: [
        { value: "true", label: "دارد", selected: true },
        { value: "false", label: "ندارد" },
      ],
    },
  ],
  []
);
```

Now use this `memoizedOptGroups`

```
<Picker
  emptyOpt={false}
  label="تخفیف نقدی"
  name="cashFlag"
  optGroups={memoizedOptGroups}
  onInputValueChange={formDataHandler}
/>;
```

Comment: hello and thank you for your reply , yes i already tried using memorized values and it worked , using the `useMemo` hook or declaring them out of component fixes the issue but . as i stated in my post , my main question is , why the arrays are being newly referenced ? 
i put a `useEffect` in my parent component and i saw that the parent component is not being changed upon state change . doesn't `useEffect` execute the callback whenever the component is re-rendered ? also , the formState is no where used in rendered content . so as i expect , parent shouldn't even re-render , and it doesn't

Comment: useEffect(() => console.log('component - rerendered')) . Add this log inside your parent component . And check whether it is getting printed more that once .But If your parent component re-renders and doesn't want your child to re-render then you should wrap the `Picker` with `React.memo`

Comment: yes sir , that's exactly how i tested the parent comp and it did not print the log more than once , that's weird , but i guess i am gonna  stick to the useMemo then .
thank you